# WooCommerce session expired hooks ( on browser back button click, after successful order )

Tags: woocommerce

When an order has been received, the user is redirected from the checkout page to the 'thank you'/confirmation end point.

At this point if/when the user clicks the 'back' button in the browser they are returned to the checkout page with the notice 'Sorry, your session has expired. Return to shop'.

I want to hook into this action so the page automatically redirects at this point instead of remaining on the empty checkout page showing this notice.

I've tried a number of hooks but to no avail -- any pointers here would be appreciated?